# Rails 3.2 iterate through an array

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3.1, hash, iteration

I have an array that looks like this:

```
@shipment_products
[
  {"old_qty_shipped"=>"324", "product_id"=>"1", "qty_shipped"=>"12443"}
  {"old_qty_shipped"=>"4343423", "product_id"=>"3", "qty_shipped"=>"321344"}
  {"old_qty_shipped"=>"23", "product_id"=>"4", "qty_shipped"=>"321"}
]
```

I want to end up being able to do something like this

```
@shipment_products.each do |p|
  Product.adjust_qtys(p.old_qty_shipped, p.qty_shipped, p.product_id)
end
```

I'm getting the following error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `qty_shipped' for #<ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess:0x007f>)
```

The array is not quite in the right format to do this.  I need to find a way to be able to iterate through the key/values and extract the attributes so I can call the method I created in the model.  Any ideas?

Comment: Is there something wrong with `adjust_qtys(p[:old_qty_shipped], p[:qty_shipped], p[:product_id])`?

Comment: no.  That works just fine. This happens even if I want to puts the values of the @shipment_products array to the screen

Comment: Use p['old_qty_shipped'] instead of p[:old_qty_shipped]

Comment: @Shamithc: You can use symbols or strings with an `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess`, that's the whole point of that class.

Comment: I guess that's the "indifferent" part.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check following code.

```
   @shipment_products = [ {"old_qty_shipped"=>"324", "product_id"=>"1", "qty_shipped"=>"12443"}, {"old_qty_shipped"=>"4343423", "product_id"=>"3", "qty_shipped"=>"321344"} , {"old_qty_shipped"=>"23", "product_id"=>"4", "qty_shipped"=>"321"}]

    @shipment_products.each do |p|
      Product.adjust_qtys(p['old_qty_shipped'], p['qty_shipped'], p['product_id'])
    end
```

Comment: Thanks, that was easy enough.