# testing create action with nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, nested-attributes

I have a bit of a confusing rSpec issue - depending how I write my code, either the tests that describe the 'failing' specs fail or the tests that describe the 'successful' specs fail.

Here are the tests for the create action:

```
describe "POST 'create'" do

  describe "failure" do

    before(:each) do
      @attr = {name: "", type_of_group: ""}
      @student_attr = [{name: "Joe", gender: "Male"}, {name: "sally twotrees", gender: "Female"}]
      @create = post :create, student_group: @attr, student: @student_attr
    end

    it "should have the right title" do
      @create
      response.should have_selector('title', :content => "Create a new group" )
    end

    it "should render the 'new' page" do
      @create
      response.should render_template('new')
    end

    it "should not create a user" do
      lambda do
        post :create, student_group: @attr
      end.should_not change {@user.student_groups.count}
    end

    it "should flash an error message" do
      @create
      flash[:error].should =~ /please/i
    end

  end

  describe "success" do

    before(:each) do
      @attr = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:student_group)
      # @student_attr = {name: "test", gender: "Male"}
    end     

    it "should create a student_group" do  
      lambda do
        post :create, student_group: @attr
      end.should change {@user.student_groups.count}.by(1)
    end

    it "should create students" # do
      # lambda do
      #   post :create, student_group: @attr, student: @student_attr
      #   end.should change {@student_groups.students.count}.by(1)  
      # end  

    it "should flash a success message" do
      post :create, student_group: @attr
      flash[:success].should =~ /has been added/i
    end

    it "should redirect" do
      post :create, student_group_id: @group, student_group: @attr
      response.should be_redirect
    end

  end 

end
```

All of the 'failure' tests fail with this error:

```
Failure/Error: @create = post :create, student_group: @attr, student: @student_attr
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   `@student_group[students_attributes]' is not allowed as an instance variable name
```

if I write the code in my controller this way:

```
def create
  @params = params[:student_group][:students_attributes]
  @student_group = @user.student_groups.build(params[:student_group])

  if @student_group.save
    ###   RE: 'defensive coding' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502508/undefined-method-for-nilnilclass-when-pushing-values-to-an-array  
    if @params.present?
      ### https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355820/rails-3-2-iterate-through-an-array
      @params.each do |student|
        @student_group.students.create(name:"#{student[:name]}", gender: "#{student[:gender]}")
      end
    end 
    # new subject path
    redirect_to class_path(@student_group), flash: { success: "#{@student_group.name} has been added successfully" }   
  else
    @title = "Create a new group"
    flash.now[:error] = "Something's gone wrong.  Please try again!"
    render 'new' 
  end  
end
```

and all of the 'success' tests fail if the controller code is written like this:

```
def create
  @params = params[:student_group][:students_attributes]
  @student_group = @user.student_groups.build(params[:student_group])
  ### http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?pid=40056#p40056
  if @params.present?
    @student = Student.new
  else 
    @student = @student_group.students.build(@params)
  end 
  if @student_group.save
    ###   RE: 'defensive coding' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502508/undefined-method-for-nilnilclass-when-pushing-values-to-an-array  
    if @params.present?
      ### https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355820/rails-3-2-iterate-through-an-array
      @params.each do |student|
        @student_group.students.create(name:"#{student[:name]}", gender: "#{student[:gender]}")
      end
    end 
    # new subject path
    redirect_to class_path(@student_group), flash: { success: "#{@student_group.name} has been added successfully" }   
  else
    @title = "Create a new group"
    flash.now[:error] = "Something's gone wrong.  Please try again!"
    render 'new' 
  end  
end
```

the form code is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17591802/2128691

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this code:

```
def create
  @student_group = @user.student_groups.new(params[:student_group]) 
  @params = params[:student_group][:students_attributes]
  @student_group = @user.student_groups.build(params[:student_group])
  if @student_group.save
    ###   RE: 'defensive coding' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502508/undefined-method-for-nilnilclass-when-pushing-values-to-an-array  
    if @params.present?
      ### http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355820/rails-3-2-iterate-through-an-array
      @params.each do |student|
        @student_group.students.create(name:"#{student[:name]}", gender: "#{student[:gender]}")
      end
    end 
    redirect_to new_student_group_subject_path(@student_group), flash: { success: "#{@student_group.name} has been added successfully.  Next, add the subjects for this group" }   
  else
    ### http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?pid=40056#p40056  
    @student = @student_group.students.build
    @title = "Create a new group"
    flash.now[:error] = "Something's gone wrong.  Please try again!"
    render 'new' 
  end  
end
```

Answer (score 0):

from the above code it seems that your controller code is really messed up. In case of nested attributes, u just have to save the parent object. the child objects get saved automatically if they are valid. Also u dont need to assign the params the some instance object. they should be used directly. a simple example of nested attributes can be

```
User
  has_many :comments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments

Comment
  belongs_to :user
```

ur controller code should be as

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user]) 
  if @user.save
    flash[:notice] = 'success'
    redirect_to some_path and return
  end
  render 'new'
end
```

the rspec controller test case can be as

```
it "should create a user with comments if valid data is provided" do
  post :create, "user"=>{"name"=>"Prasad", "comments_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"comment"=>"first comment"}, "1"=>{"comment"=>"second comment"}}, "commit"=>"Save"
  user = assigns[:user] #assigns lets u access the instance variable from the controller in the spec
  user.should be_valid
  user.comments.count.should == 2 #check that all the child models are saved
  user.name.should == "Prasad"
  user.comments.first.comment.should == 'first comment'
  user.comments.last.comment.should == 'second comment'
  response.should be_redirect(some_path) #since u redirected in the code 
end
```

seriously, u need to go through rails guides.

Comment: Agreed, my rspec testing is not really up to snuff - I'm basically using tests from analogy from the Hartl tutorial.

Comment: As for the controller code, it works as it is - certainly it can be refactored, but...it works.  whereas the code you wrote is very simple and quite to the point - and totally useless for me. The view i'm writing is quite a lot more complicated than a new user form and AFAIK logic belongs in the controller.  So if you want to have another go without being sanctimonious, you're welcome to try (and I'll happily defer to your experience), otherwise...

Comment: @dax i just wanted to demonstrate to u a simple example of nested attributes. Ur requirements may be different and so the code can change. but there is always a right way of coding and u code shouldnt depend upon the test cases. Its the other way round.

Comment: ah, maybe that's a big part of the problem then - the way i've understood TDD from what I've read is that tests come first and the code covers them.